# Match two dictionary key-values with correct order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
dict2 = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

My goal is to write the keys of dict1 as the headers of a CSV, and the values of dict2 and any other dictionaries as the values corresponding to each header.

I want the first column of the csv to be "b", so I created a new dict and added "b" first to retain order, then updated it with the remainder of dict1:

```
new_dict = {}
new_dict["b"] = fields["b"]
new_dict.update(fields)
```

So now, the two dicts that I care about are:

```
new_dict = {b:2, a:1, c:3}
dict2 = {a:1, b:1, c:3}
```

Since I'm writing the keys of new_dict to be the headers of a CSV, the CSV will now be in order: b, a, c. How can I write/change dict2 so that order of values correspond with the respective headers?

I tried:

```
for new_dict_key in new_dict.keys():
  row[new_dict_key] = new_dict[new_dict_key]
  writer.writerow(row.values())
```

But I think this only updates the values and not the order of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries in python are not ordered. This means that the order in which you input the key-values may not correspond to the order that is printed or evaluated.

To keep the order use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of the built-in dictionary!

> OrderedDict: dict subclass that remembers the order entries were added

So just initialize the `new_dict` with `new_dict = collections.OrderedDict()` instead of only `{}`. Also, the `csv` module also offers the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) which does almost the same but specifically designed for writting in `CSV`files. So maybe it's interesting for your case! Take a look just in case!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I looked into OrderedDict, but I'm still unsure how to move key-value pairs around. From what I understand, it keeps track of the order in which key-values are added. So, how would I changed the order of keys of OrderDict2 to match the order of keys of OrderDict1?

Comment: As an example, just create a second `new_dict_2` and do a similar procedure!

Comment: Thanks for all the help. OrderDict worked!

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python do not preserve any ordering of keys. I suggest that you use [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from Ptyhon's `csv` module. It takes a `fieldnames` parameter which specifies the order that the keys should be in as it writes the columns to the CSV output.